# Signal voice/video encryption scheme

Tags: security, web-applications, webrtc

I am trying to figure out how Signal messenger audio/video encryption works.

I have read the blog post

```
https://signal.org/blog/signal-video-calls-beta/
```

and the RFC for DTLS-SRTP

```
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5764
```

what I don't understand is how the DTLS handshake is actually made.

1. My first question is where does it feed the initial certificates does it uses the identity keys for both parties to negotiate the TLS session ?
2. It uses webrtc for android, with eliptic curves, and looking into the source code I can see it uses, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA or if compiled with  boringssl TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. So any ideea how is compiled ? The sources for webrtc, where it works with the encryption algorithms are in 
   https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/5647a2cf3db888195c928a1259d98f72f6ecbc15/webrtc/base/opensslstreamadapter.cc.

Thank you.